# In swiftui view, declare a function, when clicked, it does not print, where is the problem?

Tags: swiftui

```
    struct TapContentView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @State private var action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .onTapGesture {
                self.action?()
            }
    }

    public func callbackFunc(arg: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View
    {
      print("callbackFunc arg:\(arg)")
      self.action = arg
      return self
    }
}


TapContentView{
  Text("view")
}.callbackFunc {
  print("callbackFunc")
}
```

In swiftui view, declare a function, when clicked, it does not print, where is the problem? Where is the problem, the content does not print out

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of little details that need to be changed:

1. Don't use `@State` -- it's just a regular property here
2. Return `Self` instead of `some View`
3. `self` will be immutable, so you must return a copy

```
struct TapContentView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    var action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
            .onTapGesture {
                self.action?()
            }
    }
    
    func callbackFunc(arg: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self
    {
        var copy = self
        copy.action = arg
        return copy
    }
}
```